# How to replace special characters in JSON data while displaying the datatable?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I stuck for replacing special characters in JSON data while displaying in datatables, here issue is one of the column I would like to show XML formatted text, but it showing "" (null)  values, please share me your ideas, I tried with below code, but throwing some issues,

```
 var str;
   var jsonData = {"aaData": [{"USER_NAME" : "Binod","PASSWORD" : "pass123","EMAIL_ID" : "gmail.com"},{"USER_NAME" : "Param.1","PASSWORD" : "Param.2","EMAIL_ID" : "Param.3"},{"USER_NAME" : "Ritesh","PASSWORD" : "pass123412","EMAIL_ID" : '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'},{"USER_NAME" : "ajit","PASSWORD" : "pass123","EMAIL_ID" : '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'},{"USER_NAME" : "dfd","PASSWORD" : "dsfd","EMAIL_ID" : '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'},{"USER_NAME" : "dinesh","PASSWORD" : "abc","EMAIL_ID" : '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'},{"USER_NAME" : "dinesh1","PASSWORD" : "abc","EMAIL_ID" : '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'},{"USER_NAME" : "dinesh12","PASSWORD" : "abc","EMAIL_ID" : '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'},{"USER_NAME" : "dinesh123444","PASSWORD" : "abc","EMAIL_ID" : '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'}]}


        function applyEscapeChars(jsonData)
                    {

                                     str = jsonData;     
                                    var specialChars = new Array();
                                    specialChars[0] = "&";
                                   specialChars[1] = "\"";
                                    specialChars[2] = "'";
                                    specialChars[3] = "<";
                                    specialChars[4] = ">";
                                    var escapeChars = new Array();
                                    escapeChars[0] = "&amp;";
                                    escapeChars[1] = "&quot;";
                                    escapeChars[2] = "&apos;";
                                    escapeChars[3] = "&lt;";
                                    escapeChars[4] = "&gt;";

                                    for (var i =0; i < specialChars.length; i++ )
                                    {                             
                                                                    str = str.split(specialChars[i]).join(escapeChars[i]);
                                    }
                                    //alert(str);
                                    return str;

                    }

            $('#example').dataTable( {
                        "aaData": jsonData.aaData,
                        "aoColumns": [
                        { "mDataProp": "USER_NAME" },
                        { "mDataProp": "PASSWORD" },
                        { "mDataProp": "XML_Data" }   
                        ]                            
                    });
        $('body').on("click", ".dataTable tr" ,function () {

        $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");

            });
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/259/)

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: There is a error in console, please replace this line and check var str = jsonData;

Comment: @Stanze i tried the same but getting the same issue

Comment: your code is applyEscapeChars(jsonData )? (jsonData is variable line 2) and jsonData convert to xml?

Comment: No need to convert xml format, just we have to displayed one datatable with JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

In your code var declared is with capital letter '`V`' make it lowercase and try.